# Rails - good practice to specify the action available for a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are there any benefits to specify only the routes available in the routes.rb like:

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
```

Instead of leaving out the actions even if there are no views on action method in the the controller, like:

```
resources :users
```

If it's a good practice, what are the benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see couple benefits here beside not being a lazy Engineer ;)

#### DRY routes, clean code

You might have lots of routes in your Rails application at some point. Limiting the REST routes to only the one you need will help you to see what routes are actually available from your application.

When running `rake routes`, having only useful routes will be way more efficient that having all bunch of used and unused routes merged together.

#### Routes are parsed in order

Every time you or someone makes a HTTP request on your server, Rails has to parse your route(s) file(s) to find a match.

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line.

Having unused routes might slow down Rails parsing at some point (you wont see any differences with a small amount of routes).

Answer (score 2):

Limited resource routing will make your code easier to follow.

The smaller you can make the routing table, the less memory it will take up - and the less processing time route recognition and generation will take.

It can also lower the attack surface of your application by removing unused routes, which is a security win.